# Cannot acess my newly installed ruby server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu-12.04

I followed a [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm) to install ruby on rails; looks like it is installed but I can't access, check out the versions

after all I've checked both versions

```
paulo@homeserver:~$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.8
paulo@homeserver:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
```

when I type in browser

```
192.168.1.20:3000 (ip server in my local network)
```

The page can't be loaded, I have no idea how can I get this working, its the first time I'm using ruby,

Any help?

As requested this is the output of rails s command

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -V, [--skip-action-view], [--no-skip-action-view]      # Skip Action View files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Comment: Have you actually started the server (by running 'rails server')? Edit: having read that tutorial, it stops after you've installed rails. After that you have to create a rails application and start the server.http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-rails-project

Comment: did you start the server? `rails s` ?

Answer (score 0):

After you installed `ruby` and `rails`, you need to create an application with

```
rails new my_app_name
```

then you will be able to start it using `rails server`(or just `rails s`).

Follow [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html) for detailed, explained examples.

Comment: Trying this solution, lets see the result, ater is done how i can acess it via browser and where is located in machine?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. You will be able to access application via browser, after the server is started.

Comment: Thats the problem i cant acess via browser after the installation

Comment: Edited the question with info

Comment: You should create app as I said with `rails new myapp`, then enter the directory with app `cd myapp` and only from this directory run `rails s`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65898/discussion-between-paulo-jose-oliveira-rosa-and-rustam-a-gasanov).